# Drop and Recreate Index on MYSQL table, it will improve the performance?

Tags: mysql

I have Executed the query in the newly imported MySQL database but it takes 68sec to complete. Then I have dropped and recreated the same indexes on 2 main tables then it takes 24sec only.

Why it has occurred? Is it a good practice or not?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misinterpreting the results and the cause. Dropping and re-creating the indexes isn't what makes it go faster. There are two things that could be going on:

1) DB doesn't fit into RAM so when you recreated two indexes that made most of them stick in the buffer pool by the time you ran the query.

2) Table was fragmented or had very lightly filled blocks. Recreating indexes probably rebuilt the table and that may have improved page occupancy If your query requires a full table scan, this would have meant fewer GBs of table to scan and possibly less fragmented (can matter on spinning rust).

As a general rule you should never need to do that. If you disable the query cache (query_cache_type=0, query_cache_size=0 on MySQL < 8), and run the query twice, the second time is the speed you can expect with hit buffer pool.

Comment: yes I agreed with you, I ran the query many times but I got in 68sec that's why I recreated the index. your second thing is most probable with my case I have two questions to ask to you why it's occurred. 1) Anything related to the import or export process. 2) Any side-effects will occur in drop and recreate indexes.

Comment: 1) If you are restoring using INSERT-ing, this can result in fragmentation as space is allocated page by page (16KB pages), and InnoDB doesn't wait for 100% page occupancy before switching to a fresh page. Rebuilding a table doesn't work the same way, and you will typically get a smaller .ibd file on disk after a restore if you do `ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE=InnoDB;` (I am assuming you are using InnoDB since it isn't the 20th century any more.) 2) There are no side effects, but it is slow.

Comment: I would also add that if your query is taking 24-68 seconds to complete, there is likely a lot of disk churning going on, your indexes aren't as optimal as they could be, and your memory size isn't as appropriate to the task as it should be. What comes to mind is that rebuilding an index will have updated the index stats, which can affect the execution plan. So you need to check whether the execution plan is in fact the same before and after the index rebuilds (use `EXPLAIN`). If the index stat update is the cause, you should be able to update it without rebuilding with `ANALYZE TABLE`.